# Type Mismatch as I filter through a for loop (vba)

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a type mismatch error as I am looping through this for loop. It starts off fine but then it says type mismatch. I thought it would be ok as If the cell did not equal the phrase "completed", it would all be copied over into a new cell, so I didn't think it would be an issue.

After 20 rows or so, at

```
If MasterList.Cells(i, 32).Value = "Completed" Then
```

is where I got the error and not sure why it is happening. The first few rows worked fine. Thank you in advance!

```
Sub BucketReview()
    Dim BucketReport As Variant
    Dim BucketReportWB As Workbook
    Dim CopyLastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet, MasterList As Worksheet
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    'Improves Performance
    BucketReport = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select your Fee Report", FileFilter:="Excel Files(*.xlsx*),*xlsx*")
    If BucketReport <> False Then Set BucketReportWB = Application.Workbooks.Open(BucketReport) Else Exit Sub

    Set wsDest = Workbooks("Test Fee Deduction Plan Master List.xlsm").Sheets("Paste Reporting Here")
    Set ws = BucketReportWB.Worksheets("Queue Status")
    ws.Unprotect
    
    ws.Columns("A:B").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    ws.Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    ws.Columns("D:W").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    
    'paste into A, B , C
    Set wsDest = Workbooks("Test Fee Deduction Plan Master List.xlsm").Sheets("Paste Reporting Here")
    ws.Range("C:E").Copy wsDest.Cells("1", "A")
    ws.Range("A:B").Copy wsDest.Cells("1", "E")
    
    'vlookup on the masterlist
    Set MasterList = Workbooks("Test Fee Deduction Plan Master List.xlsm").Sheets("Master List")
    
    'total row number
    RowCountTotal = MasterList.Cells(Rows.Count, 29).End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Column C
    'FPNameCount = MasterList.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    MasterList.Columns(3).ClearContents
    MasterList.Range("C1").Value = "FP Name"
    MasterList.Range("C2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(F2,'Paste Reporting Here'!A:F,5,FALSE)"
    MasterList.Activate
    MasterList.Range("C2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C" & RowCountTotal)
    'copy and paste as values
    MasterList.Range("C2:C" & RowCountTotal).Copy
    MasterList.Range("C2:C" & RowCountTotal).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
    'Column D
    'FPCodeCount = MasterList.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    MasterList.Columns(4).ClearContents
    MasterList.Range("D1").Value = "FP RR Code"
    MasterList.Range("D2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(F2,'Paste Reporting Here'!A:F,6,FALSE)"
    MasterList.Activate
    MasterList.Range("D2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D" & RowCountTotal)
    'copy and paste as values
    MasterList.Range("D2:D" & RowCountTotal).Copy
    MasterList.Range("D2:D" & RowCountTotal).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
    'Column AF
    MasterList.Columns(32).ClearContents
    MasterList.Range("AF1").Value = "Reporting Status"
    MasterList.Range("AF2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(F2,'Paste Reporting Here'!A:C,2,FALSE)"
    MasterList.Activate
    MasterList.Range("AF2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AF2:AF" & RowCountTotal)
    'copy and paste as values
    MasterList.Range("AF2:AF" & RowCountTotal).Copy
    MasterList.Range("AF2:AF" & RowCountTotal).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
    'Column AG
    MasterList.Columns(33).ClearContents
    MasterList.Range("AG1").Value = "Exception Description"
    MasterList.Range("AG2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(F2,'Paste Reporting Here'!A:C,3,FALSE)"
    MasterList.Activate
    MasterList.Range("AG2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AG2:AG" & RowCountTotal)
    'copy and paste as values
    MasterList.Range("AG2:AG" & RowCountTotal).Copy
    MasterList.Range("AG2:AG" & RowCountTotal).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
    'Exceptions
    
    Dim ActionableItems As Workbook
    Set ActionableItems = Workbooks.Add
    Dim ExceptionRowCount As Long
    
    For i = 2 To RowCountTotal
        
        ExceptionRowCount = ActionableItems.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        'error at this if statement
        If MasterList.Cells(i, 32).Value = "Completed" Then
        'Do nothing
        Else
            If MasterList.Cells(i, 33).Value = "No Fee Charged for this Month" Then
                'Do nothing
            ElseIf MasterList.Cells(i, 33).Value = "This account will be verified for account closure as no funds are detected in the account. If the account is closed, it will be removed from the Fee Deduction Process. Otherwise, it will run next month as expected." Then
                'Do nothing
            Else
                MasterList.Range(i & ":" & i).Copy ActionableItems.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ExceptionRowCount, "A")
            End If
            
        End If
            
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: `MasterList.Cells(i, 32).Value ` is probably an error value - #DIV/0!, #NA or similar. Use `IsError` to test before comparing to `"Completed"`.